# JSTL get the FORWARD_REQUEST_URI (in Expression Language)

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have a page that is

```
mypage/whatever.jsp
```

But I actually want the url that is displayed in the browser:

```
foo/bar/index.jsp
```

I can get it using:

```
<%= request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_REQUEST_URI) %>
```

But I need to set it as a variable using jstl.

I tried:

```
<c:set var="topic" value="${request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_REQUEST_URI)}" />
<c:out value="${topic}" />
```

Comment: Where do you use RequestDispatcher.forward.

Comment: I've used it on my .jsp page...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `${request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_REQUEST_URI)}` represents expression language (EL), which doesn't work as intended. First, you cannot simply put method call on request object. The `request` is implicit object and `.` is correct operator, but `getAttribute` is not recognized by EL. Second, you cannot reference constants from EL - the `RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_REQUEST_URI` is not recognized by EL. If you want to use EL, try `${requestScope["javax.servlet.forward.request_uri"]}`.

Comment: Not ${request["javax.servlet.forward.request_uri"]}. It must be ${requestScope["javax.servlet.forward.request_uri"]}

Answer (score 0):

```
<c:set var="myString" value="${requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.request_uri']}"/>
```

Comment: Other way to do the same <c:set var="myString" value="${pageContext.request.attribute['javax.servlet.forward.request_uri']}" />